# How to leave a socket client always open working, even after sending the text, please?

Tags: sockets, tkinter, server, client

I have a code that sends a pre-established "hi" text to a server using socket.

1- When you finish sending the text "hi", the client closes.

2-I would like the client to remain open, even after sending the "hi"

3- Why do I want this? Because I want to create a button in tkinter, so that every time I press it, the "hi" appears. But the first time I press "hi", the client closes, and it is not possible to press other times.

What do I do please???

Server

```
from socket import *
import cv2
imagem = cv2.imread("foto.png")

host = gethostname()
port = 7777

print(f'HOST: {host} , PORT {port}')
serv = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serv.bind((host, port))
serv.listen(5)


con, adr = serv.accept()

msg = con.recv(1024).decode()
print(msg)

if msg == "hi":
    cv2.imshow("Original", imagem)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Client

```
from socket import *

from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry('430x300')


host = gethostname()
port = 7777
cli = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
cli.connect((host, port))


def bt4():
    msg = ("hi")
    cli.send(msg.encode())


btn = Button(root, text='hi', width=40, height=5, bd='10', command=bt4)
btn.place(x=65, y=100)


root.mainloop()
```

The tkinter interface with the button, it is possible to press only once to send a "hi":

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what I did, but I understood, and I managed to solve it, at first it worked, Thank you!
In case anyone has the same question

Socket

```
from socket import *
import cv2
imagem = cv2.imread("foto.png")

host = gethostname()
port = 4444

print(f'HOST: {host} , PORT {port}')
serv = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serv.bind((host, port))
serv.listen(5)


while 1:
    con, adr = serv.accept()

    msg = con.recv(1024).decode()
    print(msg)

    if msg == "hi":
        cv2.imshow("Original", imagem)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Client

```
from socket import *

from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry('430x300')



def bt4():
    host = gethostname()
    port = 4444
    cli = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    cli.connect((host, port))
    msg = ("hi")
    cli.send(msg.encode())


btn = Button(root, text='hi', width=40, height=5, bd='10', command=bt4)
btn.place(x=65, y=100)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: But won't it be slow, every time you press the button you have to start the server?

Comment: no? it doesn't start the server every time you press the button?

Comment: However this does leave a socket open on each end, when it isn't used any more. Perhaps after 1000 clicks or more, you will start getting errors that you have too many open sockets.